# Matlab command for writing string into excel

Tags: string, excel, matlab, command

I am trying to write a string in a cell in an excel file using Matlab by the following command:-

**xlswrite('E:\project\messidor\Testing image.xls','hello',1,'A3');**

but the problem is each character of the word **hello** is written in a different cell.

In this example I want the word **hello** to be written in cell **A3** but h is written in A3, e is written into 'B3',l is in 'C3' and so on.

Pls suggest correct command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the value `'hello'` in a cell array, like this:

```
xlswrite('E:\project\messidor\Testing image.xls',{'hello'},1,'A3');
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) for more information.